# jQuery clone() function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know but the below code is not working. it is working fine when I add td instead of p.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("th:contains('2G Band') ~ p").clone().appendTo("#2g");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Clone element</button>

<tr class="RowBG2">
  <th rowspan="3" scope="rowgroup" style="text-align: left;vertical-align: top;" class="hdngArial specs-mainHeading bottom-border-section">Frequency</th>
  <th scope="row" align="left" class="hdngArial specs-subHeading RowBG1 bottom-border">2G Band</th>
  <p class="fasla RowBG1 specs-value bottom-border"><b>SIM1:</b> GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900<br><b>SIM2:</b> GSM 850 / 900 / 1800 / 1900 &nbsp;</p>
</tr>

<tr class="RowBG2" style="background-color: #ebf1fa; color: #666666; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;">
  <td class="hdngArial" height="25" style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold;">&nbsp;2G &nbsp;Band&nbsp;
  </td>
  <td id="2g" colspan="2"></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid, `p` element cannot be direct descendant of `tr` element and btw, `tr` element must be nested inside `table`

Comment: It's quite hard to picture what you want here. You haven't given a much information. Is this meant to be a table?

Comment: So, why don't you add `td`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason it works with `td` and not with `p` is because a `p` is not supposed to be part of the table structure (i.e. not a direct desendent of `tr`.

You have two choices.

- wrap the `p` with a `td`.
- replace the `p` with a `td`.